# Что такое цитируемые вопросы?

Tags: поддержка, вопросы, поиск

Не понимаю, что это такое...

> [image: скриншот]

Comment: Подозреваю, что это вопросы, на которые стоит больше всего ссылок в других вопросах. Но это не точно.

Comment: Судя по всему - это сортировка по количеству "связанных" вопросов - отметок дубликатов и прямых ссылок